# Hover event converts to click on mobile except iPhone / Safari?

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit confused about this but I think I've found the issue.

I have in my html:

```
    <div class="dropdownz">
        <button>HOVER_OR_CLICK</button>
        <div class="dropdownz-content">
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my css I have:

```
.dropdownz {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdownz-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownz:hover .dropdownz-content {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

So this basically means if I hover over the `dropdownz` class, the `dropdownz-content` display converts from `none` to `block` and the menu items show.

When I run this on an android touchscreen mobile device, I have to CLICK the `dropdownz` item in order for it to effect the `hover` and show the list, if I click it again, it effectively removes the hover.

This is desirable behaviour, it means I don't have to do any extra stuff for touch-screens. A "hover" becomes a click and the 2nd click removes the "hover". Great!

Apparently this doesn't work the same in SAFARI on an iPhone. I can't test it myself, I'm going via a friend who says it's not working, so I basically want to know:

**Is this a known issue** and what's the best way to remedy it? (Without JavaScript, surely!)

I'm thinking along the lines of `:focus` ?

Comment: Clicking to get hover state is standard across all mobile browsers, your code works as expected on my iPhone in Mobile Safari(clicking displays the dropdown content and clicking again hides it).

Comment: You can try adding `:active` and `:focus` to your CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
.dropdownz:hover .dropdownz-content,
.dropdownz:active .dropdownz-content,
.dropdownz:focus .dropdownz-content{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'd considered this but wondered if it was necessary. I'll add it and see if it changes it for him.